# Arrow With UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Help me to achieve the following layout using UIButton in iOS.
Don't mark this as duplicate, pls let me know exact working solution

[image]

Comment: you can draw the arrow programmatically below the button!

Comment: Add background image like this when your button is selected.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati any open source available for it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `UIControlStateSelected` property

```
[yourButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourNormalImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourArrowImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

And on every click update state of your button to selected.

```
[yourButton setSelected:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to set the image on the button as you need. I am justing pointing out some of the important methods on `UIButton` below:

1. `+[UIButton buttonWithType:buttonType]` - Make sure if you're doing anything remotely custom to use `UIButtonTypeCustom` here (it doesn't
   give you any default background images or otherwise to have to `nil`
   out)
2. `setFrame:` - Position the button relative to its container and set
   the size, for usability reasons the width and height should be at
   least 44 pixels.
3. `setTitle:forState:` - `UIControlStateNormal` will act as the default
   properties for other states too, so you may only need to set the
   text here.
4. `setBackgroundImage:forState:` - use `UIControlStateNormal`, 
   `UIControlStateHighlighted` & `UIControlStateSelected` primarily. Use
   `UIControlStateDisabled` if you wish to show it grayed out or
   inaccessible at any point.
5. **`setImage:forState:` - Use for an icon next to the button text (like
   an arrow pointing down)**
6. `setEnabled:`, `setHidden:`, `setSelected:` - Transition between different
   button states. setHighlighted: happens automatically when you tap
   the button.
7. `addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside` - TouchUpInside is
   almost always what you want for a simple button press. `buttonClicked:` method here to handle button press.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an image view with this arrow image. Then add button on this image view however you need to adjust height width x & y properties of button. 
After that when you click on any button set the image of image view corresponding to all other buttons to nil and set the image view image to be arrow image of the button you clicked.